# Checking BASH strings in while loops for single quotes?

Tags: bash

Looking to check if a string doesn't contain single quotes in the following syntax, 'text' (although it could also be 'text','text','text') but haven't been able to escape the quotes properly as to allow the opening of a while loop. 
Code:

```
while [[ -z "$projects" ]] || [[ "$projects" =~ *"\'" ]]; do
    <reprompt user, read var, and reset variable>
done
```

The above is the best I've dreamt up, but it only looks for an ending ', and doesn't even work properly at that as testing with "a" does not result in entering the loop. How should I be testing for badly formatted user strings when single-quotes come into play?

Comment: did you try to `grep` for it?

Comment: @mike.k Yes, although I'm hesitant to create a loop with an if that I need to break.  It felt like there must be a more bash way to do this. Got a little closer with:
    `while [[ "$projects" != "'"*"'" ]] ;do`
That passes most test cases, although it lets '' through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right-hand side of the `=~` operator is a regular expression not a glob/pattern.

If you run `[[ "$projects" =~ *"\'" ]]; echo $?` you'll see that you get a return code of 2 (which means pattern error). You get that because you can't start a regular expression with `*`.

You also don't need or want to escape the single quote *inside* the double quoted string (since you don't want a literal `\'` you just want the single quote).

Your pattern only matches a trailing single quote because you only allow for a wildcard match at the start of the string. You can fix that by adding `*` (or `.*` for the regex operator) to the end of the pattern as well.

So you either want

```
[[ "$projects" = *"'"* ]]
```

for the pattern matching version of this test (alternatively `*\'*`).

Or you want

```
[[ "$projects" =~ "'" ]]
```

for the regular expression version of this test (again alternatively `\'`).

Comment: `=~` does a substring match, so `=~ \'` will work fine

Comment: @rici I thought about that and then forgot to confirm my memory before posting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like what I ended up needing was:

`while [[ "$projects" != "'"?*"'" ]];do`

This will catch null values and ensures that there is at least one character in between the single quotes.